# CreateView return "Experience.id_auth_user" must be a "AuthUser" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a CRUD on Django, i have the table of users and the table of experiences, each user can have multiple experiences, so i want to assign the user-id to the new experience. When i try to do that i get an error "Experience.id_auth_user" must be a "AuthUser" instance."

**Models.py**

```py
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    perfil_photo = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    cel_number = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
class Experience(models.Model):
    experience_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    minimum_age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_auth_user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_auth_user', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'experience'
```

**views.py**

```py
class ExperienceCreate(CreateView):
    model = Experience
    fields = ['experience_name','description','duration','price']
    def form_valid(self, form):
#        form.instance.id_auth_user = Experience.objects(id_auth_user=self.request.user.id)
        #instance_experience = Experience.object.id(id_auth_user=self.request.user.id)
        #form.instance.id_auth_user = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.id_auth_user = self.request.user.id
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('experience')
```

any suggest?

Comment: Rename this attr and stop confusing yourself. Making it `auth_user = models.ForeignKey` would result in `auth_user` attr of type AuthUser, `auth_user_id` attr and db column of type int. Also, did you set AUTH_USER_MODEL? If not then `self.request.user` is not of type AuthUser. If it is then correct code would be `self.object.auth_user = self.request.user` or `self.object.auth_user_id = self.request.user.id`.

Comment: change `self.object.id_auth_user = self.request.user.id` to **`self.object.id_auth_user = self.request.user`**